# How to store a multi-line text in sql server 2005 using SSMS?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, database-connection, ssms

I got similar questions to this but not get satisfied answers. I want to store paragraph in table in sql server 2005. I tried all data types (nvarchar, varchar, text etc.) but when I copy the content, it store only 1st line. Help me.

I am using Sql Server Management Studio and directly copy paste the content into table. And for retrieving I use this code.

```
String query2 = String.Format("select data from try where roll=55");
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
if (reader2.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = reader2.GetValue(0).ToString();

    }
```

where 'data' is multiline content.

Comment: Can we see your ADO.NET code that does the storing?

Comment: @HackedByChinese Actually, I want to store paragraph manually in sql server 2005. And in ado.net I am retrieving it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'paragraph'?

Comment: @Viktor then can you show us the SQL Query that you are running?

Comment: @Steven 'paragraph' means 'multiline'

Comment: How exactly are you storing this multi-line text? Are you using SQL Server Management Studio and are copy-pasting this directly into a table? With tool or method do you use?

Comment: @Steven Ya, you are correct. I use SSMS and directly copy-paste into table.

Comment: Do you use the `Edit top 200 rows` command from the context menu?

Comment: @Steven , I read all answers but none of them is suitable for me. Actually I want to directly copy-paste the content in table. Is there anyway to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little test using Sql Server 2008-R2 (So it might be different on 2005):

```
insert into Test1 (Col1) VALUES('THIS
INSERTS

A

Multiline

String')
```

When selecting, the result DOES look like there are no line-breaks, BUT if you check for char(10) and char(13) - (CRLF) they DO exist in the string...

```
select col1, REPLACE(REPLACE(col1,CHAR(10), 'X'),CHAR(13), 'Y') as LineBreaks from Test1
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set SSMS to return values as text rather than grid (button on toolbar) you can see the line breaks in the text, they aren't displayed in the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I have a web application that I help maintain, we store the data from a multiline textbox in SQL server 2008 R2 -- inserted with ADO.Net and Pulled using ADO.net  At first glance it appears that the breaks in the "paragraph" are missing.  To recover the line breaks for a printable version of the data, I utilize a quick regular expression to place the breaks back in the web app.  The method used to do this is below:

```
    public static string lineBreakCharsToHTMLBreak(string sourceString)
    {
        // This regex says look for any tab, carriage return or linefeed
        Regex rexNewLine = new Regex("[\\t\\n\\r]");
        sourceString = rexNewLine.Replace(sourceString, "<br>");
        Regex rexDoppleBreak = new Regex("(<br>){2,}");

        sourceString = rexDoppleBreak.Replace(sourceString, "<br>");

        return sourceString;
     }
```